# Reloading scene causes Update Function to stop working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm reloading the scene after a user clicks on retry. The Update function does not work after reloading the scene.

I searched the web and found `DontDestroyOnLoad()`, but I don't know how can I use it with a function.

Used

```
 Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); 
 SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);
```

to reload the scene.

Is this a bug from the unity side or i need to do something else before reloading the scene.

Comment: You haven't included enough information here to adequately diagnose the problem. `DontDestroyOnLoad()` takes a game object parameter. That game object (and all its components) will not be destroyed when `LoadScene` is called, but if the new scene also contains that game object, you will end up with a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the object witch the script is in not be destroyed when you load a scene using `DontDestroyOnLoad()`. But when you load the same scene there will be already the same object in that scene, so you will have to destroy it.

```
private static GameObject goInstance;
void Awake(){

    if (goInstance == null) {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        goInstance = gameObject;
    } else {
        //destroy duplicate
        Object.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
 }
```